# IntelliJ view compiled bytecode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bytecode

I've just started programming and I have a quick question regarding IntelliJ.

I've used different IDEs to practice the simple "HelloWorld" application, just to get a feel for the IDE.

I have one issue, I created my application for the code

[image: See here]
but I get this error when I try to view the bytecode for the compiler:

[image: See here again].

I have already compiled using the command "javac Main.java" and it clearly displays a Main.class and Main.java but I'm unsure why it won't display the bytecode.

I'm not 100% sure if I even really need to be able to see the bytecode as an aspiring developer however I am trying to get as much exposure as I can.

(Now that I think about it, could this have anything to do with JVM itself? Should I reDL and install?)

Comment: Hello man, could you copy and past the error here instead of showing that as image on an external site? Thanks

Comment: Dont compile it manually. Let your IDE do the job. Just create your code and hit the run button. The IDE will put the compiled output into the `bin` folder.

Comment: You don't need to see the bytecode, certainly not at this stage

Comment: @sigur Can you edit your improvement to add an exclaimation mark at the begin of image link text to show the image directly?

Comment: @sigur , That was a screenshot that I clipped myself using gyazo however the error is "Bytecode not Found - Unable to parse class file for 'Main'.

For everyone else,
I was compiling it manually as part of a tutorial. The tutorial is
https://youtu.be/Qgl81fPcLc8?t=1683 
(I clipped it at the specific time he mentions it)

Comment: @AlgorithmFromHell Thanks for the heads up! I was just following along for the tutorial but it's good to know that I shouldn't worry too much about it currently however it is an anomaly that I'm worried if I don't decipher now, it could come back to bite me so that's why I'm curious as to why Im receiving the error message. Google searches were a bit too saturated so that's why I came here

Comment: When you really need to see the bytecode, since you're an "aspiring developer" you will want to become *au fait* with the generic tools so do `javap -c x.y.z.SomeClass` at the command line

Comment: The latter. Always use the source ;)

Comment: @AlgorithmFromHell That's not true. If something doesn't work as expected, it is always nice to go one layer below.